# Extra tree classifier missing argument y

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

So I was trying to implement Extra Tree Classifier in order to find the parameters importance in my data base, I wrote this simple code but for some reason I keep getting thiss Error.

My Code:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline


from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier 



df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ali97\\Desktop\\Project\\Database\\5-FINAL2\\Final After Simple Filtering.csv')

extra_tree_forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators = 5,  criterion ='entropy', max_features = 2) 

extra_tree_forest.fit(df)

feature_importance = extra_tree_forest.feature_importances_ 

feature_importance_normalized = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in extra_tree_forest.estimators_], axis = 1)

plt.bar(X.columns, feature_importance_normalized) 
plt.xlabel('Lbale') 
plt.ylabel('Feature Importance') 
plt.title('Parameters Importance') 
plt.show()
```

The Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4aad8882ce6d> in <module>
     16 extra_tree_forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators = 5,  criterion ='entropy', max_features = 2)
     17 
---> 18 extra_tree_forest.fit(df)
     19 
     20 feature_importance = extra_tree_forest.feature_importances_

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, for fit function, we need to have both attributes(X) and labels(Y) and you need to use `extra_tree_forest.fit(X, Y)` to train this classifier.
I recommend you split labels and attributes and import them as two separate lists when you import 
`Final After Simple Filtering.csv`.

Comment: So I can not apply it on the whole dataframe at once instead of splitting the database?

Comment: You can do something like this here (for example if you have 10 columns of X and the rest are labels): 
X = data.iloc[:, 0:10]
Y= data.iloc[:, 10:-1]

Comment: You cannot apply the fit function on Whole data at once.

Comment: I trried the iloc and I got "ValueError: at least one array or dtype is required"

Comment: There might be white spaces in your labels (Y) column. please take a look at the CSV file and remove any space in that column.

Comment: My csv files has been completely filtered from any zeros, nan values or empty cells

Comment: @AliYoussef make sure that you have a column for labels (Y) in your dataset and also debug the code line by line to see which line makes that error.

Comment: Unfortunately that still didn't work , I'm getting "at least one array or dtype is required"

Comment: @AliYoussef Can you copy the error. I want to see which line you see that error?

Comment: It's data.iloc[:, 0:10]

Comment: Oh I see. Replace Data with df. that was an example:
`X = df.iloc[:, 0:10]`  and `Y= df.iloc[:, 10:-1] `@AliYoussef

Comment: yet again I'm getting "at least one array or dtype is required"

Comment: @AliYoussef I copied your code and applied it on my own dataset. I could run it completely. I am pretty sure that you have not considered the correct indices in `X = df.iloc[:, 0:10]` and `Y= df.iloc[:, 11]`. Try the column number(for example 11) instead of something like 10:-1.  
Or there is a white space in your data.

Comment: So my database consits of 13 columns, I'll try X as X = df.iloc[:, 0:13] and Y as Y= df.iloc[:, 1] , I'll tell you how it goes. I'm 100% certain my dataset has 0 white spaces.

Comment: @AliYoussef I guess the correct index for Y can be 13 `Y= df.iloc[:, 13]` or other columns.

Comment: So I've tried Y= df.iloc[:, 1] and X=df.iloc[:,0:13] and got "Unknown label type: 'continuous' "

Comment: @AliYoussef Now open your excel file and find which column is your label(Y). Note that in python column 0 stands for the first column.

Comment: @AliYoussef you are passing floats to a classifier which expects categorical values. Please select the right column as label(Y). `Y= df.iloc[:, Change this] `

Comment: I'm trying to run the code, with Y= df.iloc[:,0] and X= df.iloc[: ,0:12], but the code is using all 16GB of RAM even put low_memory=True still crashes, also tried Google Colab which has about 25GB ram on cloud, still crashes.

Comment: That would be another problem. I think it is related to your problem size. If you are using google colab go to Run time>change Run time > select GPU. Just as a final note please do not select one column both as label and attribute! change `X= df.iloc[: ,0:12]` to `X= df.iloc[: ,1:12]`

Comment: Yes I have chosen the run time as GPU , still crashing. Also for X , I have chosen 1:12 not 0:12, I'll tell you how it goes if it runs.

Comment: The porblem ended up being that the max_depth had to be set to 10 or less, anymore would make it run out of ram, I have accepted your answer. Thank you for your help!